# Do you get anything for clean killing all legendary animals?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

It is known that clean kills are not necessary for perfect pelts from legendary animals. But does anyone know if you get anything special for clean killing all legendary animals? They have clean kill descriptions in the compendium, I wonder if there might be something to it.